# I get an Eclipse error: conversion to 'uint16_t' from 'int' may alter its value

Tags: c

I'm using Eclipse for STM32 and I find out there are many errors related to the type of number. I defined a function with the proper return type but I still get an error when invoke it.

```
uint8_t HEX_Parse(char c) 

//this one is ok
uint16_t sum =(uint16_t)(HEX_Parse(Buffer[strlen(Buffer)-3])*16);

//this one get an error    
sum += (uint16_t)HEX_Parse(Buffer[strlen(Buffer)-2]);
```

Why?  How do I fix it?

Comment: The warning is correct; the conversion may change the value.  Expressions of type `uint16_t` (usually equivalent to `unsigned short`) are promoted to `int` before any arithmetic happens.  So, the summing operation has arithmetic done in `int` type and then converted to `uint16_t`.  The straight assignment converts `uint8_t` to `uint16_t`, which is a lossless conversion and therefore doesn't elicit a warning (and neither should it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter assignment is identical to:

```
sum = sum + (uint16_t)HEX_Parse(Buffer[strlen(Buffer)-2]);
```

The expression `sum + (uint16_t)HEX_Parse(Buffer[strlen(Buffer)-2])`, actually has the type `int`, because of integer promotions.
And as there are no casts to do the explicit conversions, the compiler warns about the implicit conversion from `int` back to `uint16_t` when the `int` expression `sum + (uint16_t)HEX_Parse(Buffer[strlen(Buffer)-2])` is assigned to `sum`.

You should cast to the whole expression:

```
sum = ( uint16_t )( sum + HEX_Parse(Buffer[strlen(Buffer)-2]) );
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks, I solved the problem with your method, think eclipse is too strict on syntax, since i copied those sentences from other IDE while it works.